# Align buttons in toolbar using Ionic with React

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

How do I align the back button to the left and the hamburger menu icon to the right of the toolbar. Could anyone please help?

```
<IonToolbar mode="ios">
  <IonButtons slot="start">
    <IonBackButton defaultHref={route} />
    <IonMenuButton color="dark" />
  </IonButtons>
  <IonTitle>
    App Title
  </IonTitle>
</IonToolbar>
```

**Current result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an other `IonButtons` and give a `slot` property on it ( either `start` or `end` ). That should align your buttons in the toolbar.

```
<IonToolbar mode="ios">
  <IonButtons slot="start">
    <IonBackButton defaultHref={route} />
  </IonButtons>
  <IonButtons slot="end">
     <IonMenuButton color="dark" />
  </IonButtons>
  <IonTitle>
    App Title
  </IonTitle>
</IonToolbar>
```